# Recently attempted to install latest version of ubuntu as my OS off my USB but it's not installing to the hard drive?

Tags: boot, usb, hard-drive

Updated

To answer questions in the comments:

1) It is not dual-boot on my first attempt of the installation process I had it erase the windows 10 that it came with.

2) I'm unsure if secure boot is disabled or not as I'm not sure how I would check that (I'm in the learning process so I appreciate the patients)

I remade my USB boot making sure that Rufus was set to "MBR partition scheme for UEFI" and attempted to install the desktop once more. I did notice that when I started the Rufus program a window popped up stating that "This image uses Syslinux 6.03/20170128 but this application only included the installlation files for Syslinux 6.03/2014-10-06. As new versions of Syslinux are not compartible with one another two additional files must be downloaded from the internet (ldlinux.sys and ldlinux.bss) select yes to connect to the internet and download these files". This window pop up wasn't included in the tutorial in creating the USB boot so I thought it may hold some significance in my problem.

I followed these two tutorials exactly:

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#3

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0

However, still when I'm given the restart prompt and remove my USB I'm given a prompt that I need to install a OS to the hard drive. When I plug back in my USB boot it brings me directly back to the start up menu to install again. I hope this additional information helps in discovering why Ubuntu wont install onto my hard drive. Thank you for the help.

Ubuntu 17.04, HP elite book 840 G3, all specs are within the requirements to run Ubuntu smoothly.

Comment: Have you installed in UEFI or Legacy mode? If you don't know what I'm asking you probably did it wrong...

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you very much.

Comment: See  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi & http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789